# namespace - nobody to root mapping

Tags: linux, root, namespaces

I'd like to create new user namespace being root with the command:

```
# unshare -U bash
$ echo $$
3500
$ id
uid=65534(nobody) ... etc
```

After that I edit /proc/3500/uid_map im my initial namespace as root:

```
# echo "0 100000 65536" > /proc/3500/uid_map
```

My /etc/subuid file I've created:

```
root:100000:65536
```

Now when I'm back in newly created user namespace by unshare:

```
# exec bash
uid=65534 ... etc
```

still get nobody user.
Is root not allowed to create mapping for himself? Or I'm doing something wrong? :)

Comment: IMHO 
Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be root within the new namespace, why not

> unshare -Ur bash

?